# add multiple key/value pairs to object from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function arrayToList (arr){
    var dataStructure = null;
    for (var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
    dataStructure= {value: arr[i]};
    }
    return dataStructure;
}
arrayToList([1,2,3]);
```

I would simply like this function to create an object that like this:

```
dataStructure {
    value: 1;
    value: 2;
    value: 3;
}
```

So far my code keeps updating a singular value. I'm pretty sure I cannot have "value" (same name) multiple times, however, I failed at trying to change it to value, value1, value2, etc. as well

Thank you in advance, sorry newbie question

Comment: Keys must be unique!

Comment: You cannot have multiple keys with the same name in an object.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply Ibrahim! Any input on how to update the value name?

Comment: Why do you want unique keys `value1`, `value2`, etc? That doesn't seem useful. How about just having `value` reference an Array? `dataStructure = {value: [1,2,3]}`. All depends on the end goal.

Comment: Hi Squint - I'm not sure of usefulness, just a curiosity of what's possible.  It's just a deviating thought I had from a challenge question in the Eloquent Javascript book

Comment: the original problem asked for this output: var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};  ---I just wondered how to do it without the referencing

Comment: _"the original problem asked for this output: `var list = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }`"_ That is a different data structure than described at original Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define object before `for` loop, use bracket notation to set property of object. You can also pass a second parameter to specify the the value to be concatenated to object properties.

```js
function arrayToList (arr, counter) {
    var dataStructure = {};
    for (var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++, counter++){
      dataStructure["value" + counter] = arr[i];
    }
    return dataStructure;
}
var res1 = arrayToList([1, 2, 3], 1);

var res2 = arrayToList([4, 5, 6], 4);

console.log(res1, res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arrayToList (arr){
    var dataStructure = {};                // data structure is initialized to an empty object
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var key = "value" + i;               // generate the key (or var key = "value" + (i + 1); if you want to start with value1, value2 ...)
      dataStructure[key] = arr[i];         // set the value of the key 'key' to arr[i]
    }
  
    return dataStructure;
}

var obj = arrayToList([1,2,3]);

console.log(obj);
```